# How can I disable the image magnifier when I click the button again? I only need one button for this

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I get the image magnifier in this link:

https://thdoan.github.io/magnify/

Then I entered this code inside the body:

```
<img src="img/1.jpg" id="image" class="zoom" data-magnify-src="img/1.jpg">
<img src="img/2.jpg" id="image" class="zoom" data-magnify-src="img/2.jpg">
<img src="img/3.jpg" id="image" class="zoom" data-magnify-src="img/3.jpg">
```

I also added a button where it will trigger the effect:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Magnify</button>
```

I was able to magnify the image when I click the button, however, I also want that when I click the button again, the image magnifier will close.

Here is my script:

```
<script src="jquery.magnify.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.zoom').magnify()
            });;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: So do you want to close magnifier when user clicked as second time?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Yes. that's what I want to happen